# Grid changes width when ScrollViewer is added to it

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, scrollviewer

I am absolute beginner to Windows store app and today i was trying to add ScrollViewer in an app i was trying to create. So, when i run the following code the left column takes 90% screen width and Right column takes 10% of the width:

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Header" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SubHeader :" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="30" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="526" Margin="90,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="This is left Column"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid Width="800">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" />
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Heading" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="40" Margin="80,36,0,0" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Black"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="30" Text="This is Right Column" Margin="60,0,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
```

But when i add ScrollViewer to it the width of left column decreases and width of right column increases.

```
   <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Header" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SubHeader :" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="30" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="526" Margin="90,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="This is left Column"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid Width="800">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" />
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Heading" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="40" Margin="80,36,0,0" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Black"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="30" Text="This is Right Column" Margin="60,0,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I guess that the way i am adding a scrollviewer is wrong. Could anyone please guide me how to add horizontal scrollviewer in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Of course your column widths are changing when adding a scrollviewer. This is because your columns are trying to fit any content inside them so that the scrollviewer can **scroll** to them. 
Try removing the content from your inner grids and you will see that the column widths are preserved. If you want to keep the column widths to a ratio of 9:1 you will have to declare a scrollviewer for each column, as such:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="9*" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.2*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                           FontSize="50"
                           FontStyle="Italic"
                           Text="Header" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                           FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                           FontSize="30"
                           FontStyle="Italic"
                           Text="SubHeader :"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1"
                  Height="526"
                  Margin="90,60,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="This is left Column" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
        <Grid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" />
                </Grid.Background>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.2*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Margin="80,36,0,0"
                           FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                           FontSize="40"
                           FontStyle="Italic"
                           Foreground="Black"
                           Text="Heading" />
                <Grid Grid.Row="1"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock Margin="60,0,0,0"
                               FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                               FontSize="30"
                               Foreground="Black"
                               Text="This is Right Column" />

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

On a sidenote, there is no need to explicitly set `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column` to **0** as that is their default value.

Comment: okay i get it but when i run the code a tiny scroller is visible in right column only. usually a single scroller covers the total width of the screen but in this code scroller is visible only in the right column.

Comment: If you want a single scrollviewer you'll need to set fixed widths for the columns